# SQL Query to get the monthly change percentage from daily quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table and I would like to get the Monthly change % from it

[image: Data Image]

I am using the below query for getting the monthly change:

```
SELECT 
    ct.Quote_Date, ht.Quote_Date AS htDate, ct.Quote_Price, 
    ht.Quote_Price AS [htPrice], 
    ((ct.Quote_Price - ht.Quote_Price) / ht.Quote_Price) * 100 AS ChangePerc
FROM 
    #TempStock ct 
LEFT JOIN 
    #TempStock ht ON CONVERT(DATE, CAST(ct.Quote_Date AS VARCHAR), 101) = DATEADD(MM, 1, CONVERT(DATE, CAST(ht.Quote_Date AS VARCHAR), 101))
ORDER BY  
    ct.Quote_Date DESC
```

Result of this query:

[image: Result Image]

Everything working fine except when the ht.Quote_Date is Sunday or Saturday or a holiday for which the record is missing in the table. In this case the available date before the holiday should be considered so that i don't get the NULLs as shown in the result image above.

Could you please let me know the correct query to get the required result ?

Comment: So after looking at your code and considering your text you are looking for a method to compare a quote_date with a future quote_date exactly 1 month in the future but then to adjust that date to be earlier than the actual future date if a value is not available.  Typically this would be done the other way around agust 8th would look at july 8th and compare the % difference.  Is that what you actually want?

Comment: also are you on sql-server 2012+?

Comment: Yes, I want agust 8th would look at july 8th and compare the % difference. But if July 8th is a Holiday then it should look out for July 7th or if July 7th is also a holiday, then it should look out for July 6th. I am on SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OUTER APPLY could help you:

```
SELECT  ct.Quote_Date, 
        ht.Quote_Date AS htDate, 
        ct.Quote_Price, 
        ht.Quote_Price AS [htPrice], 
        ((ct.Quote_Price - ht.Quote_Price)/ht.Quote_Price)*100 AS ChangePerc
FROM #TempStock ct 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #TempStock 
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,CAST(ct.Quote_Date AS VARCHAR),101) >= DATEADD(MM,1, CONVERT(DATE,CAST(Quote_Date AS VARCHAR),101))
    ORDER BY Quote_Date DESC
    ) ht
ORDER BY  ct.Quote_Date DESC
```

WHERE clause in OUTER APPLY will bring first record with same or lesser date.

Comment: 10 seconds and the right thought but you also have the datetime converted and looking for the future month not the previous month which is understandable because it was the OPs original mistake that I had discussed in comments with him

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `outer apply`:

```
SELECT ct.Quote_Date, ht.Quote_Date AS htDate, ct.Quote_Price,
       ht.Quote_Price AS [htPrice],
       ((ct.Quote_Price - ht.Quote_Price)/ht.Quote_Price)*100 AS ChangePerc
FROM #TempStock ct OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 ht.*
      FROM #TempStock ht
      WHERE ht.Quote_Date <= DATEADD(month, -1, ct.Quote_Date)
      ORDER BY ht.Quoate_Date DESC
     ) ht
ORDER BY ct.Quote_Date DESC;
```

Notes:

- You should do date arithmetic using *dates*.  There is no reason to cast back and forth to strings.
- If the dates have time components, use `cast(<col> as date)` to get rid of the time component.

Comment: 10 seconds difference :)

Comment: yep exactly what I was thinking and gordon beat me to it, but note if you do have a time component to the quote_date field, which might be why you are using the convert, simply cast it as a date and it will drop it off so WHERE CAST(ht.Qoute_date AS DATE) <= DATEADD(month, -1, CAST(ct.quote_date AS DATE))

Comment: The Reason Why I am using the Cast is that the date is stored as Gregorian in the table eg. 8/11/2016 is stored as 20160811

Comment: CAST('20160811' as DATE) will give you a date datatype '08/11/2016' so if you use the where statement I provided in my last comment it should still get you want you want